# Setting initial value for ng-model in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I've searched Stack Overflow for an answer to my question but I can't seem to find a solution that works.

I have two select tag that follow this format:

```
select(required class='form-control nf-input' ng-model='Game.loadedGame.teams[0].teamInfo' ng-change='Game.addTeam(Game.loadedGame.teams[0])',
                             ng-options='team.name for team in Game.teams | orderBy:"name" | preventSameMatchTeams:Game.loadedGame.teams[1].teamInfo.id'
                             )
```

I am trying to initialize the ng-model for this select by passing in Game.loadedGame into this function after the server responds with the correct data:

```
function setLoadedGameTeams(loadedGame, teams) {
        loadedGame.teams.forEach(matchTeam => {
            let index = teams.findIndex(team => team.id === matchTeam.id);
            if (index !== -1) {
                matchTeam.teamInfo = teams[index];  
            }
        });
    }
```

The select dropdown isn't changing to the correct option after I set the teamInfo property on each team, even though the view is properly updated to show each team's information.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I discovered is very simple. I simply had to add a track by to the ng-options!